# Should web service be called inside a Model class in MVC framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, .net-4.0

Suppose I have WCF web service that that can retrieve collection of `<Person>` objects.  My question is where should I place the code to call the web service, the controller or the model?  My second question is should I also create my own `<Person>` class in my model folder or just use the one that auto generated when added service reference in .NET project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically I'll have the Controller use the WCF service to load the data, which can sometimes also be the Model. In more complicated apps you will likely want something to translate what WCF returns (data transfer objects) into your Models, which is really outside the "MVC" pattern.

---

You might want to review the [Nerd Dinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/) example and see how they have their code organized. It was intended to be a "real-world" example of a fairly well structured MVC3 application.

Hanselman also has a roll-up review of a couple different NerdDinner forks that did different styles of data access [on his blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExtendingNerdDinnerExploringDifferentDatabaseOptions.aspx).

---

*Code snippet for @Splash-X*

What I was trying to get across in my "not part of the MVC pattern" comment was that sometimes the DataModel (what the DB or WCF returns) isn't the same as the ViewModel (that you send to the View), so sometimes you may need something to translate between the models, like:

```
public interface ITransformer<out To, in From>
    where To : class
{
    To Transform(From instance);
}

public class SomeDataToSomeViewModelTransformer : ITransformer<SomeViewModel, SomeDataModel>
{
    public SomeViewModel Transform(SomeDataModel instance)
    {
        return new SomeViewModel
            {
                InvitationId = instance.Id,
                Email = instance.EmailAddress,
                GroupId = instance.Group.Id
            };
    }
}
```

Any my comment was intended to imply that the thing "transforming" between models isn't dictated by the MVC pattern. Or more generally, don't feel that just because you are following MVC that means that you can *only* have 3 class types. Not *everything* is a Model, View or Controller.  The Controller can and will use other classes that aren't prescribed by the MVC pattern itself.

That was all I meant by my comment.  Again, I realize it wasn't the best worded remark. Sorry.

Comment: When you need to transform into something else to send it to a view (ex: adding meta markup for field validation or combining several models) we term that a ViewModel. I wouldn't say that using a ViewModel is outside of the MVC pattern. There are a lot of situations where you don't want your database entities or web services entities as your models.

Comment: In general, where should your data access code be in the MVC pattern?

Comment: @Splash-X : I guess I didn't word that very well. What I meant was that the Controller would make a call to some kind of `DataModel` to `ViewModel` transformer / translator, and that "transformer" class isn't a Model, View, or Controller. Sorry for the confusion. @qin : typically I have the Controller load the data, through some kind of `Repository` that abstracts out the actual database.

Comment: The "M" in MVC doesn't stand for "Data Model", it stands for "Model". The Model can be any type of model (view model, data model, dynamic or anonymous model). To say that fetching data from a source (Database, Webservice, Memory, etc) and creating a different Model based on that data to send to the View doesn't match the MVC pattern is a bold statment. If this were the case why would there be anonymous or dynamic models?

Comment: I added some text to the end of my answer with a code snippit to better explain what I meant by "not part of MVC pattern". In hind sight it was a poorly worded remark, and I should have just omitted it.

Answer (score 0):

Calling WCF from Controler is true. If you call service insede Model that your model dependent  to service, this is not good usage for MVC. Models shouldnt be dependent to service. Calling from controller best choice

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on what you want to do with the data once you've retrieved it.

If you plan on putting it in a database, it shouldn't happen in either a controller or a model, but in a lower layer.

If you plan on immediately displaying it on a page - ie, get the data from the service and the add it to your model - you can call the service from your controller, but my personal preference is to move that call to another class that can handle all of the communications messiness without cluttering up the controller, especially since you might need to do this from other controllers.

Code that isn't explicitly related to the model - such as validation, and even then only in some cases - doesn't belong in the model, and code that's not explicitly for getting models into and out of the view, or calling a lower layer to perform further processing of the model, doesn't belong in the controller.